# $\lvert\,X^2/∼\,\rvert$ given $\lvert\,X/∼\,\rvert = n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

let ‘∼’ be an equivalence relation on a set X. Define a binary relation (denoted by the same symbol ‘∼’) on X$^2$: for any x, y, x′, y′ ∈ X
(x, y) ∼ (x′, y′)⇐⇒ x ∼ x′and y ∼ y′

(a) Prove that this is an equivalence relation on X$^2$

(b) Assume that |X/∼| = n. What is |X$^2$/∼|?

I understand how to do part a (Show its reflexive, symmetric, transitive), but I have no idea how to do part b.  Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: Hint: It should be easy to find a bijection between $X^{2}/\sim$ and $(X/\sim)^{2}.$

Comment: @RideTheWavelet I see why its an injection, but why is it onto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $|X^2 / \sim | = n^2$. To see this note that there is a bijection between $X^2 / \sim$ and $(X/ \sim)^2$ defined by sending $[(x,y)]$ to $([x],[y])$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the equivalence class. One should make the straightforward checks that this map is well-defined and really is a bijection.

Comment: I get why it is injective, but why is it onto?

Comment: For $([x],[y])$ in $(X / \sim)^2$, consider $[(x,y)] \in X^2/ \sim$. Under the above map it gets sent to $([x],[y])$.

Answer (score 1):

So let's say your equivalence classes of $X$ under $\sim$ are $$X = c_1, \uplus \ldots \uplus c_n.$$ Then, a typical equivalence class of $X^2$ should look like $c_j \oplus c_k$, can you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Choose a set of representatives of classes $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}=R$ of $X/\sim$, and work to show that $\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in R\}$ is a set of representatives for $X^2/\sim$.